# How to load Android Studio on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio on Ubuntu 16.04 and had started a project. I wanted to carry on with it but I can't find anywhere to load Android Studio from. Is there a command I can use on the command line to load Android Studio?

Edit: 
[This is what I want opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrWII.png)

Comment: what do you mean by "loading android studio"? Is it to start the program, create/loading a project, link an android device connected by USB or starting an android emulator?

Comment: @damadam I want to load the starting page that asks you if you want to start a new project, load an existing project, etc

Comment: So, all you're looking for is a button to click on to start the program?

Comment: @T.Green you can start the program with or without command line, just like firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start Android Studio from the terminal type:

```
cd /opt/google/android-studio/bin  
./studio.sh
```

If you get a `bash: /.studio.sh: No such file or directory` error, browse to the opt directory, search for the android-studio directory, and try to find the studio.sh file from there.